# Passing custom command-line arguments to a Rust test

Tags: c++, rust, command-line-arguments

I have a Rust test which delegates to a C++ test suite using [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/) and wants to pass command-line parameters to it. My first attempt was

```
// in mod ffi
pub fn run_tests(cli_args: &mut [String]) -> bool;

#[test]
fn run_cpp_test_suite() {
    let mut cli_args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if !ffi::run_tests(
        cli_args.as_mut_slice(),
    ) {
        panic!("C++ test suite reported errors");
    }
}
```

Because `cargo test help` shows

```
USAGE:
    cargo.exe test [OPTIONS] [TESTNAME] [-- <args>...]
```

I expected

```
cargo test -- --test-case="X"
```

to let `run_cpp_test_suite` access and pass on the `--test-case="X"` parameter. But it doesn't; I get `error: Unrecognized option: 'test-case'` and `cargo test -- --help` shows it has a fixed set of options

```
Usage: --help [OPTIONS] [FILTER]

Options:
        --include-ignored 
                        Run ignored and not ignored tests
        --ignored       Run only ignored tests
...
```

My other idea was to pass the arguments in an environment variable, that is

```
DOCTEST_ARGS="--test-case='X'" cargo test
```

but then I need to somehow split that string into arguments (handling at least spaces and quotes correctly) either in Rust or in C++.

Comment: Slightly orthogonal answer to your question - can we not set environment variable for the test; if the sole purpose it to pass some arguments to a UT? Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858323/how-can-i-test-rust-methods-that-depend-on-environment-variables ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are *two* pieces of Rust toolchain involved [when you run `cargo test`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html).

`cargo test` itself looks for all testable targets in your package or workspace, builds them with `cfg(test)`, and runs those binaries. `cargo test` processes the arguments to the left of the `--`, and the arguments to the right are passed to the binary.

Then,

> Tests are built with the `--test` option to `rustc` which creates an executable with a `main` function that automatically runs all functions annotated with the #[test] attribute in multiple threads. `#[bench]` annotated functions will also be run with one iteration to verify that they are functional.
>
> The libtest harness may be disabled by setting `harness = false` in the target manifest settings, in which case your code will need to provide its own `main` function to handle running tests.

The “libtest harness” is what rejects your extra arguments. In your case, since you're intending to run an entire other test suite, I believe it would be appropriate to disable the harness.

1. Move your delegation code to its own file, conventionally located in `tests/` in your package directory:

   ```
   Cargo.toml
   src/
       lib.rs
       ...
   tests/
       cpp_test.rs
   ```
2. Write an explicit [target section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#configuring-a-target) in your `Cargo.toml` for it, with harness disabled:

   ```
   [[test]]
   name = "cpp_test"
   # path = "tests/cpp_test.rs"   # This is automatic; you can use a different path if you really want to.
   harness = false
   ```
3. In `cpp_test.rs`, instead of writing a function with the `#[test]` attribute, write a normal `main` function which reads `env::args()` and calls the C++ tests.

[Disclaimer: I'm familiar with these mechanisms because I've used Criterion benchmarking (which similarly requires disabling the default harness) but I haven't actually written a test with custom arguments the way you're looking for. So, some details might be wrong. Please let me know if anything needs correcting.]

Comment: Thanks, to be honest I expected it wouldn't be possible! I should have time to check it (and then accept the answer) tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Kevin Reid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65794217/5397009), if you don't want to write your own test harness, you can use the [`shell-words` crate](https://crates.io/crates/shell-words) to split an environment variable into individual arguments following shell rules:

```
let args = var ("DOCTEST_ARGS").unwrap_or_else (|_| String::new());
let args = shell_words::split (&args).expect ("failed to parse DOCTEST_ARGS");

Command::new ("cpptest")
    .args (args)
    .spawn()
    .expect ("failed to start subprocess")
    .wait()
    .expect ("failed to wait for subprocess");
```