# Passing arguments to cargo test with clap

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, rust-cargo, clap

The program takes an path to a configuration file. E.g. `cargo run -- -c path/to/yaml`.
This does not however work with cargo test. `cargo test -- -c path/to/yaml` and following error will occur: **error: Unrecognized option: 'c'**.

#### Attempts and research

Clap provide a method `fn from_args() -> Self`, but did not fully know how this would solve the problem. [A similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791697/passing-custom-command-line-arguments-to-a-rust-test) was solved by making it a integration test and add

```
[[test]]
name = "cpp_test"
# path = "tests/cpp_test.rs"   # This is automatic; you can use a different path if you really want to.
harness = false
```

to the cargo.toml file.
In my case I want to test some functions and thus unit test. I do not believe this would work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using cmd args inside test, but this seems really like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791697/passing-custom-command-line-arguments-to-a-rust-test). Hope you can find a solution there.

Comment: It is a similar question, but not quite the solution. I guess theirs solution was to make it a integration test and disable the harness. I also found a [discussion]((https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/test-and-external-test-harnesses/3145) that may be relevant. I will also add this to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to have a `fn main_body(args: Args)` that does the real work, and then just test `main_body` by passing the args directly in your source code instead of on the command line.

```rust
use clap::Parser; // 3.1.18

#[derive(Parser)]
struct Args {
    #[clap(short, long)]
    name: String,
}

fn main_body(args: Args) -> Result<(), ()> {
    // Your main body here
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    let args = Args::parse();
    main_body(args)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let args = Args { name: "Bob".into() };
        assert_eq!(main_body(args), Ok(()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that would be possible. But if I want to use a function, e.g. create_connection() that is used for multiple other functions, this would be cumbersome. That means I have to pass args from main, to every other functions that will use create_connection().

Comment: @Eirik I would argue that that's the correct design. Relying on global, hidden, unvalidated, unparsed state present in `std::env::args()` seems like a much more brittle and difficult-to-understand design than parsing the args once and then passing the resulting data around wherever it's needed.