# cargo comandline arguments parse minus float

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How to parse a minus float in cargo? like

```
#[test]
fn test1() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

and run it with

```
cargo test --release test1 -- -1.0 --nocapture --exact
cargo test --release test1 -- '-1.0' --nocapture --exact
cargo test --release test1 -- "-1.0" --nocapture --exact
cargo test --release test1 -- `-1.0` --nocapture --exact
/xxx/test_bin test1 -1.0 --nocapture
```

It says `error: Unrecognized option: '1'`
with `rustc 1.64.0-nightly (6dba4ed21 2022-07-09)`

Comment: What are you trying to do? To which program you want to pass minus one?

Comment: Looks like the argument is passed to the Rust standard test harness. Not sure how it is expected to be used, however.

Comment: The test harness needs to parse every argument, so you can't use command line arguments yourself

Comment: Maybe relavent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791697/passing-custom-command-line-arguments-to-a-rust-test

Comment: what do you mean by `you can't use command line arguments yourself`?