# Setting environment variables with Cargo only for tests

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've set an environment variable using [config.toml](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) file:

```ini
[env]
FOO = "bar"
```

Is it possible to set `FOO` only for tests so that if run `cargo build` I don't see FOO but I do if I run `cargo test`? Or to set a different value for tests?

Comment: maybe you can check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858323/how-can-i-test-rust-methods-that-depend-on-environment-variables